# Splitting one path into two

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

So I have this path that looks like this:

[image: Connected Path]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: Unconnected Path]

Is there a way to do this without redrawing the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use the `Eraser` tool, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. You can click anywhere to erase that part of a path. Double click the tool or use <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to change the brush size.

Be warned that the eraser will erase any and all paths, unless you make a selection. If something is selected, the eraser will only erase from the selection and leave all other paths intact.